# Netty 3.95 Channel write and using setTrafficClass

Tags: netty, channel

I have a Netty 3.95 Client and Server.  The client sends mission plans to the server.  There is essentially no limit to the number of plans that can be sent and some plans are more important than others.  I have three priorities (high, medium, low) and I assign each mission plan a priority (DSCP value as I read the data into the client.)  I am hoping that this allows more important mission plans to arrive at the server first.

I have turned down the router's outbound data rate to its minimum and I have flooded the router with about 1000 plans.  I can see the mission plans arrive at the server and they arrive very slowly.  This tells me I have been effective locking down the outbound data rate from the router.

Right before I do a channel.write for each mission plan I get the configuration for the channel and set the traffic class.

```
private void setTrafficClass(int code) {
    comLink = connection.getChannel();
    cfg = (NioSocketChannelConfig) comLink.getConfig();
    cfg.setTrafficClass(code);
}
```

I then follow this with a

```
comLink.write();
```

The mission plans always arrive in the order that I send them.  It almost seems like the DSCP codes are ignored.  DSCP is enabled in the router.  I used Wireshark to examine the traffic between the client and the server and I noticed that not all the DSCP codes were correct.  It almost seems like a group of mission plans are written at once and whatever the DSCP code was for the last one becomes the code for the group.  Nevertheless, some is not correct.

Questions

1. Is there a more efficient way to use the channel.write()?  I wanted to flush the channel after every write but I did not see this method.  Does one exist that I haven't stumbled upon?
2. Is there any reason why writing the trafficClass right before each write is not working correctly?
3. I tried grouping mission plans with the same DSCP and writing them as a unit.  I would write the low , then the medium and then the high, thinking the router would adjust the delivery, but this did not work either.

---

#### Solved

I have solved the issue or better yet a coworker looked at my code and we discovered the problem.  I had a race condition in my code which did not allow the proper DSCP codes to be set.  If you look at my setTrafficClass method you can see that I pass in the code that I want to set, however it is important to realize this code is setting the connection and not the actual packet DSCP.  Since I was literally sending 100s of mission plans as quick as possible the code was constantly changing the connection's traffic class.  Given enough time, it was unable to keep up and hence the behavior I would see.

The solution was quite easy because of the Netty API.  In my case I only use 2 DSCP codes so I declared two connections.  One connection would deal with the DSCP code 0 packets and the other connection would deal with the DSCP code 46 packets.  Once I put this code into play, I was able to see both DSCP codes arrive at the sender as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have answer for all, I think.

1. In Netty 3.9, you can wait on the `channel.write()` returned future, or better to start the next write on a ChannelFutureListener of your own as:

   ```
   channel.write().addListener(yourChannelFutureListener);
   ```

You shall not block the IO Worker thread, so the reason to use a listener. However, if it is too complicated, you can just add a `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` in your pipeline, just before your application handler, such that it is executed outside of the IO worker thread and then using await().

In Netty >= 4, you will have a `writeAndFLush()` method, which is simpler.

2. First of all, trafficClass is really dependent on the Java implementation of the socket as far as I know. It might be ignored (as said in the Java doc (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTrafficClass(int) ).

Also note that values in IPV4 are limited (see Javadoc).

However, I'm not an expert of that point, but I suppose that order is kept whatsoever the code, since it is as far as I know mandatory from TCP point of view. I believe that in UDP it shall work as you want (since ordering in not ensured).

3. For the reason state above (ordering), I believe you have to write in the reverse order if you want high priority to reach first the target.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would perform the prioritisation in code rather than rely on the network to do it. That way you insulate yourself from any peculiar network configurations your data may have to traverse.

There are a few ways to achieve this so the following is just an example.

- Read the plans in a separate thread and place on a priority queue
- Read items from the priority queue in a second thread and write to the channel
- If the channel.isWritable returns that it is no longer writable you can either block on the future that was returned, thus guaranteeing that Netty has flushed all data to the socket buffers, or listen for the channelInterestOpsChanged event to resume writing as soon as Netty flushes enough data to below the low water mark. This might be more performant as it allows you to resume preparing data while Netty is flushing the last of the previous data.

Java has provided a [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) implementation since at least Java 6. It even provides an example of how to maintain priority within a distinct priority level using sequence numbers. If your network is slow you will probably want to limit the number of outstanding plans in the queue.

You may also need to consider if starvation is a problem - i.e. whether so many high priority plans are produced that low priority plans never get sent.